# Selecting records with greater RRN

Tags: sql, db2

i have a file FILE1 which contains 2 fields name and no. There records with duplicate numbers. So i want to fetch all distinct records and when there are records with same no. select the one with greater RRN. Please suggest how to accomplish this with SQL DB2.

Comment: If this is for DB2 on iSeries, could you please tag it as such?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it.  Please note that I don't make any guarantees as to what order the records are actually in - the record number is *usually* (but not always, especially if reorged) the insert-order.

```
WITH Indexed (name, no, recordNumber) as (SELECT name, no, RRN(File1)
                                          FROM File1)
SELECT a.name, a.no
FROM Indexed as a
EXCEPTION JOIN indexed as b
ON b.no = a.no
AND b.recordNumber > a.recordNumber
```

If there are a **lot** of duplicates, this will be slow.  You *will* want an index on `no`, if the file is large.

Comment: Thanks!! But i want all distinct records plus whenever there is a situation where two distinct records have same no. then it should pick greater rrn record...Please help

Comment: @abhinavsingh - This should do that.  What's it failing on?  Is there some requirement you haven't mentioned?